# How to redirect stdout and stdin in a given file using argv in C

Tags: c, linux, shell, execvp, freopen

I want to redirect stdout and stdin in a specific file which would be given in argv array.

For instance when I enter a command like - ./shell ls > test

it should be redirected to the "test" file, now I am bit confuse because without writing any code it automatically redirects to that file, I want to do it manually, secondly, when I enter a command like- ./shell ls < test, the stdin should be redirected. I tried to find a file name and ">" or "<" sign using argv[argc-1] and argv[argc-2], but it seems that when I use ">" and a filename afterwards, the output prints(the arguments before ">" "<" sing) in that file instead of getting that name and a sign.

Basically, I am creating a shell command using execvp() and fork().

Here is my code, I am able to redirect stdout in a static file.

```
void call_system(char *argv[],int argc)
    {
    int pid;
    int status=0;
    signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
    int background;
    /*two process are created*/
    pid=fork();
    background = 0;

    if(pid<0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"unsuccessful fork /n");
         exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    else if(pid==0)
    {
        //system(argv[1]);
        /*argument will be executed*/

                freopen("CON","w",stdout);
                    char *bname;
                    char *path2 = strdup(*argv);
                    bname = basename(path2);


                        execvp(bname, argv);
                         fclose (stdout);
    }
    else if(pid>0)
    {
    /*it will wait untill the child process doesn't finish*/
    //waitpid(pid,&status,0);

    wait(&status);

    //int tempid;
    //tempid=waitpid(pid,&status,WNOHANG);
    //while(tempid!= pid);// no blocking wait


    if(!WIFEXITED(status) || WEXITSTATUS(status))
    printf("error");



                         exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    }
    }
```

Comment: Just use something other than `>` and `<`, such as `./myprog -i input.file -o output.file`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `dup()` or `dup2()` or `dup3()`.

The dup() system call creates a copy of the file descriptor oldfd,
       using the lowest-numbered unused descriptor for the new descriptor.

```
File *fp=fopen(argv[1],"r");
int fd=fileno(fp);

dup2(fd,0); //dup2(fd,STDIN_FILENO) redirect file stream to input stream
scanf("%s",buff); //reading from file.
```

Similarly output can also be redirected.From manual these informations may be useful

```
On program startup, the integer file descriptors associated with the
       streams stdin, stdout, and stderr are 0, 1, and 2, respectively.  The
       preprocessor symbols STDIN_FILENO, STDOUT_FILENO, and STDERR_FILENO
       are defined with these values in <unistd.h>.
```

Suppose you want to redirect stdout to this file.

```
dup2(fd,1);//dup2(fd,STDOUT_FILENO)
printf("%s",buff); //this will write it to the file.
```

Answer (score 0):

stdio redirection is handled by the shell, not the launched program. The relevant syscalls are `pipe`, `open` and `dup2`, the later of the two is used to redirect the stdio filedescriptors into the pipe or file to be read from or written to.